# how to compare two dataframes and flag one data frame?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Hi I have two Dataframes Like shown below and trying to get the resulted dataframe as shown below.

want to compare the data frames only with respect to ID column.

```
id  name    item    price   
1   abc      pen    10  
2   bcd      pencil 10  
3   cde      book   100 
4   def      stick  50  
5   abc      pencil 10  


id  name    item    price   
2   xyz     pen     10  
50  ahjl    phone   1000    
1   fff     mouse   200 
5   ank     stamp   20  
49  anve    cable   2000
```

result table

```
id  name    item    price   flag
2   xyz      pen    10      yes
5   ank      stamp  20      yes
1   fff      mouse  200     yes
50  ahjl     phone  1000    no
49  anve     cable  2000    no
```

am able to achieve this using python pandas.
Can you please help me in doing this with pyspark.

Thanks,

Ankush Reddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume your data frames are called `df1`, `df2` respectively:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2.join(
    df1.selectExpr("id", "'yes' as flag").dropDuplicates(), 
    ["id"], "left"
).withColumn("flag", F.coalesce(F.col("flag"), F.lit("no"))).show()

+---+-----+----+-----+----+
| id| item|name|price|flag|
+---+-----+----+-----+----+
| 50|phone|ahjl| 1000|  no|
|  5|stamp| ank|   20| yes|
|  1|mouse| fff|  200| yes|
| 49|cable|anve| 2000|  no|
|  2|  pen| xyz|   10| yes|
+---+-----+----+-----+----+
```

Details:

- Prepopulate `flag` column for `df1` with constant `yes`;
- join with `df2`, and replace `null` in `flag` column with `no`;

Comment: hi Psidom thank you for your answer. When I try to run it in my pyspark jupyter notebook it is throwing me an error saying reference id' is ambiguous, could be: 'id#57' etc

Comment: Not entirely sure. Maybe your `df1` and `df2` are derived from other tables so they could have multiple `id` columns?

Comment: Thank You that helps.
I will check it.